# tcp connection stays in CLOSE_WAIT and belongs to pid 1

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, process

My server program creates tcp socket that listens on a specific port, say p1.

By using the command "netstat -apn" i find many TCP connections on port p1 hangs in the state "CLOSE_WAIT" and related sockets seem to belong to the init process (pid=1).

The TCP connection is still out there even if my server process is killed.

I cannot figure out in what circumstances can this happen.

Comment: CLOSE_WAIT means that the peer has closed his end of the connection but you haven't. If you're forking after accepting, both parent and child processes need to close the socket. It sounds like your main server has exited but some of your forked processes haven't.

Answer (score 0):

If the parent ends, the children won't implictly die, but live on.

After the parent's dead a child gets inherited by the `init` process. The latter is defined to carry pid `1`.

Comment: can the init process take over child's socket fd?

Comment: Theoratically it could, but any sane implementation wouldn't.

Comment: Theoretically it could how? The socket is closed when the last process using it exits.